# Is it possible to use Python Azure SDK for Azure SignalR service?

Tags: python, azure, signalr

I'm trying to connect a Python application to Azure SignalR.  All examples of connecting Python to Azure SignalR that are documented use Azure Function bindings; not the full SDK.

It appears that [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/master/sdk/signalr/azure-mgmt-signalr) is likely what I need, however it is lacking in documentation.

I also attempted to connect with the `signalrcore` module using:

```
from signalrcore.hub_connection_builder import HubConnectionBuilder

hub_connection = HubConnectionBuilder()\
    .with_url(server_url, options={"verify_ssl": False}) \
    .configure_logging(logging.DEBUG, socket_trace=True, handler=handler) \
    .with_automatic_reconnect({
            "type": "interval",
            "keep_alive_interval": 10,
            "intervals": [1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 87, 3]
        }).build()
```

However, when an Azure SignalR connection string of the form `Endpoint=xxxxx;AccessKey=yyyyy=;Version=1.0;` is used, it generates errors in the `requests` module due to an unrecognized URL structure.

Comment: Currently there is no official MS provided standalone python client SDK for signalr. [This](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/master/sdk/signalr/azure-mgmt-signalr) is management only SDK, not client. [signalrcore](https://pypi.org/project/signalrcore/) is a third-party package, you may log issue in their [github](https://github.com/mandrewcito/signalrcore) repo.

Comment: Please refer to https://dev.to/mandrewcito/singlar-core-python-client-58e7